# How can I write query where query with specific where condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, plsql

I have one table with one primary key and three foreign keys.
Here my table with data

```
Id      RegistrationId        GroupId      ItemId   Value    
2345     68038                677           672      679    
3562     68038                357           783      423    
8236     NULL                 268           578      914    
7327     NULL                 677           672      467    
8733     NULL                 357           783      234
```

I want to write query to get this result

```
Id      RegistrationId        GroupId      ItemId   Value
2345     68038                677           672      679
3562     68038                357           783      423    
8236     NULL                 268           578      914
```

As you can see I want all rows that have RegistrationId 68038 and I also want other default values for other GroupId and ItemId. How can I write SQL query to get result like above ? Thanks on your responds. How can I do this in MySQL ?

Comment: your question isn't clear. what happens to last two entries?

Comment: You can see table have 5 rows and result should have three rows because last two rows from table are not shown because  RegistrationId  68038  already have values for  GroupId  677  ItemId  672  and GroupId   357   ItemId  783

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: "I've tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas"

Comment: mysql, sql-server,postgresql,plsql - which one are u using?, and how would you decide that the id 2345 should come first?. I mean is there any other datetime column which specifies the ordering or is it sequential ( though it does not appear from your resultset)?

Comment: I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged multiple databases, assuming it to be a SQL Server.

Try this query, it will give you the desired output.

```
SELECT Id,RegistrationId ,GroupId,ItemId,Value FROM
(
  SELECT * ,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY GroupId,ItemId   ORDER BY RegistrationId DESC) RN
  FROM [TABLE_NAME]
 ) T
WHERE T.RN=1
ORDER BY RegistrationId DESC
```

**Example with sample data**

```
;WITH MY AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES
  (2345 ,  68038  ,  677 , 672 , 679 ),
  (3562 ,  68038  ,  357 , 783 , 423 ), 
  (8236 ,  NULL   ,  268 , 578 , 914 ),
  (7327 ,  NULL   ,  677 , 672 , 467 ),
  (8733 ,  NULL   ,  357 , 783 , 234 ) 
  ) T(Id,RegistrationId ,GroupId,ItemId,Value)
)

SELECT Id,RegistrationId ,GroupId,ItemId,Value FROM
(
  SELECT * ,    
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY GroupId,ItemId   ORDER BY RegistrationId DESC) RN
  FROM MY
 ) T
WHERE T.RN=1
ORDER BY RegistrationId DESC
```

**Output:**

```
+------+----------------+---------+--------+-------+
| Id   | RegistrationId | GroupId | ItemId | Value |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+-------+
| 3562 | 68038          | 357     | 783    | 423   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+-------+
| 2345 | 68038          | 677     | 672    | 679   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+-------+
| 8236 | NULL           | 268     | 578    | 914   |
+------+----------------+---------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like that and it worked, but its bit a hardcoded way:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM   MY
    WHERE  RegistrationId IS NOT NULL
    AND    GroupId IN (677, 357)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *
    FROM   xxtest_tolga
    WHERE  GroupId NOT IN (677, 357);
```

Hope it works for you.